# problem with low level calls between contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation

I know this is very basic, but I just cannot get to work a low level call between contracts. I have set up two contracts. **ContractA** just adds two numbers and keeps track of the number of calls it receives:

```
contract ContractA {

    uint public lastResult;
    uint public opCount;
    event operation (address sender, uint parama, uint paramb);

    function add(uint a, uint b) public returns(uint){
        uint c = a + b;
        lastResult = c;
        opCount ++;
        emit operation(msg.sender, a,b);
        return c;
    }
}
```

**ContractB** just calls ContractA. when I call  `ContractA.add` using the interface (`callAddviaInterface`) it works ok, but when I use `callAddWithSignature`, it fails. What is it that I am getting wrong? I believe the syntax is ok.

```
interface CalleeContractInt{
    function add(uint a, uint b) external returns(uint);
    function exp(uint a, uint b) external returns(uint);
}

contract ContractB{
    address public calleeAddress;
    string signatureAdd = "add(uint, uint)";
    CalleeContractInt CalleeContract;

    constructor (address _calleeAddress){
        calleeAddress = _calleeAddress;
        CalleeContract = CalleeContractInt(_calleAddress);
    }

    function callAddWithSignature(uint a, uint b) public returns(bool success) {
        bytes memory data;
        (success, data) = calleeAddress.call(abi.encodeWithSignature(signatureAdd,a,b));
    }

    
    function callAddviaInterface(uint a, uint b) public returns(uint){
        uint c = CalleeContract.add(a,b);
        return c;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues inside `callAddWithSignature()` method:

- The low level call doesn't accept alias.

  For example: **uint** is alias of **uint256**.

  This standard for low level call doesn't accept this operation. You can solve it changing your signature method in this way:

  `add(uint256, uint256)`
- The second issues, refers to a space between the two argument in your signature method stored in `signatureAdd` variable. The standard says to remove the blank spaces between the input parameters specified in a method.
  In your case the previous signature change in:

  ```
    string signatureAdd = "add(uint256,uint256)";
  ```

In the following lines, I put your `ContractB` smart contract modified:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface CalleeContractInt{
    function add(uint a, uint b) external returns(uint);
    function exp(uint a, uint b) external returns(uint);
}

contract ContractB{
    address public calleeAddress;
    string signatureAdd = "add(uint256,uint256)";
    CalleeContractInt CalleeContract;

    constructor(address _calleeAddress){
        calleeAddress = _calleeAddress;
        CalleeContract = CalleeContractInt(_calleeAddress);
    }

    function callAddWithSignature(uint a, uint b) public returns(bool success) {
        bytes memory data;
        (success, data) = calleeAddress.call(abi.encodeWithSignature(signatureAdd,a,b));
    }

    function callAddviaInterface(uint a, uint b) public returns(uint){
        uint c = CalleeContract.add(a,b);
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: great, it worked perfectly. Thanks!